# GCP postgresql master and replica update tier issue

Tags: postgresql-11

I have created postgresql db with replica on GCP using tier "db-custom-2-7680". Primary instance and replica reflecting same configuration. but, when i try to update the tier from "db-custom-2-7680" to "db-custom-8-16384" facing an error message below-
Failed to update instance steeting, Invalid request- postgresql master can not be larger than replica...

can anyone help on this issue?

Comment: used terraform as a IAC.